# MySQL: Select Concat of strings and Length of resulting Concat

Tags: mysql, sql

In my CREATE VIEW I would like to:

```
SELECT CONCAT( t.str1, t.str2 ) AS Title, CHAR_LENGTH( Title ) AS Length
```

but this ill produce error:

> Unknown column 'Title' in 'field list'.

What is the correct way of doing this without having to Concat same strings twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot refer the alias you created in `SELECT`, use expression instead:

```
SELECT CONCAT( t.str1, t.str2 ) AS Title,
       CHAR_LENGTH(CONCAT( t.str1, t.str2 )  ) AS Length
FROM table_name t
```

You can use subquery if you need:

```
SELECT sub.Title, CHAR_LENGTH( sub.Title ) AS Length
FROM (
   SELECT CONCAT( t.str1, t.str2 ) AS Title
   FROM table_name t
) AS sub;
```

**[`All-at-once operation`](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20724.all-at-once-operations-in-t-sql.aspx):**

> "All-at-Once Operations" means that all expressions in the same
>   logical query process phase are evaluated logically at the same time.

and:

> We cannot use an alias in next column expression in the SELECT clause.
>   In the query we create a corrected first name and we want to use it in
>   next column to produce the full name, but the All-at-Once operations
>   concept tells us you cannot do this because all expressions in the
>   same logical query process phase (here is SELECT) are evaluated
>   logically at the same time.

Comment: But will SQL engine optimize this so to not perform the indentical Concat operation twice for every row?

Comment: @Pirs01 Use first version and stop worrying about performance

Comment: But if I use subquery in my Create View then I will no longer be using the MERGE algorithm so that cannot be my best option in terms of performance right? EDIT: I guess I'm already not using it since I used CONCAT and CHAR_LENGTH

Comment: @Pirs01 I don't know nothing about your MERGE algorithm, edit your question and add more details. For me you are searching performance gains in wrong place.

Comment: I was referring to CREATE [ALGORITHM = {MERGE  | TEMPTABLE | UNDEFINED}] part of CREATE VIEW syntax.

Comment: @lad2025 Why do you prefer the first version? I like to make subqueries and I think it is more readable.

Comment: So should I use the first one because it will get optimized or should I use the subquery to avoid doing the same Concat twice (don't need subquery otherwise)?

Comment: @maraca I would say it is personal taste. I don't like subqueries either and rather to use `CTE` not availabe in MySQL

Comment: @Pirs01 For such simple operation like `CONCAT` I would use first option. But the best option is to make two versions and check execution plans for both.

Comment: Bit in a rush right now but I'll try to remember to do the test some time later and will come back to report results then. Either way marking as anwsered. Thanks.

Comment: Derived tables (second query) is a great way to avoid writing the same expression several times. (And also easier to adjust later, if needed, since you only have to do it once.) Without the risk of having two different expressions!

Comment: @jarlh Did I write subqueries are bad? Of course not, but I use rule of thumb. If expression is relatively easy I would rather copy paste it instead of wraping around subquery. Personal taste. For example `SELECT col, CONCAT(...), COUNT(*) FROM tab GROUP BY col, CONCAT()` I don't like to introduce subquery when  I can avoid it

Comment: @lad2025, Did I say you said sub-queries are bad? I just said derived tables can be very convenient when the same expression is written twice.

Comment: @jarlh Your `!` mislead me :)