# MySQL 5.7 SELECT using alias not working

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

The following SQL works fine in MySQL 5.6:

`SELECT 10 AS total,
    (SELECT total * 10) AS cost`

However in MySQL 5.7 this gives the following error:

`Unknown column 'total' in 'field list'`

I'm fairly certain this is something to do with [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by), but I'm not sure how I can fix what I've got.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: [All-at-once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33723677/mysql-select-concat-of-strings-and-length-of-resulting-concat/33723693#33723693) The key is you cannot use the  alias in the same clause. Use `SELECT total, total * 10 AS cost
FROM (SELECT 10 AS total) AS sub` instead

Comment: @lad2025 Ok, bit strange this behaviour is totally different in a minor release but ah well. Thanks!