# MYSQL alias in subquery where clause

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with aliases in subqueries.

I have a query:

```
SELECT
    `id` as `t`, 
    `title`, 
    `once`,
    (select count(`id`) from `orders_files` where `order_id`='116815' and `type`=`t` and (`version`='41924') ) as `count`,
    (select count(`id`) from `orders_files` where `order_id`='116815' and `type`=`t` ) as `count_in_order`
FROM 
    `orders_filetypes`
WHERE
    `required`=1 
ORDER BY `sort`, `title`
```

**that runs and works on an older version of a mysql (5.6.22) and does not work on the new version mysql (5.7.9)**. mysql error is "#1054 - Unknown column 't' in 'where clause'".

Config files are identical, and what the problem is I don't understand.

We have updated the mysql server and many queries stopped working.
Please tell me, this feature has been deprecated in newer mysql or it can be set /etc/my.cnf?

it is not possible to find and fix hundreds of thousands of lines of code, where such requests can be used, so it is preferable to include this possibility in the new server.

thank you!

Comment: Here's the page of changes from 5.6 to 5.7 and I don't see anything exactly about this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html#upgrade-sql-changes   because you are doing a `SELECT` .

Comment: Possible duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34003818/mysql-5-7-select-using-alias-not-working  in that it also has subqueries that stopped working in 5.7.  But it doesn't say how to solve it without rewriting so I still think one or the other is a valid open question.

Comment: Thank you for link, Elin, but there are no answer for my question. The problem is in updating mysql server(configs, changes or default values), and not wrong query. The SQL query works fine on an older version mysql.

Comment: That's exactly what I said, isn't it? That it's still an open question. The problem is that the query is handled differently in 5.7  .. can you test doing this? `SET optimizer_switch = 'derived_merge=off';`  that seems to be the main  change with subqueries.

Comment: Also it would be super helpful if you would run EXPLAIN for your query in 5.6 and 5.7 and post the results.

Comment: SET optimizer_switch = 'derived_merge=off'; - that does not working. mysql complete this query, but nothing changed when I write my query with alias... I also tried set this option in my.cnf, but it does not worked too.

I run my EXPLAIN query in older version: [SQL EXPLAIN image](https://pp.vk.me/c630616/v630616502/52d9/vLaMJBXasJA.jpg)

Comment: Did you see this? http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79549

Comment: Thank you, Elin! I wrote my problem here :)

That is really bug)

Answer (score 0):

why don't use table alias and call the column by its name like this:

```
SELECT
        `id` as `t`, 
        `title`, 
        `once`,
        (select count(`id`) from `orders_files` where `order_id`='116815' and `type`=outer_table.`id` and (`version`='41924') ) as `count`,
        (select count(`id`) from `orders_files` where `order_id`='116815' and `type`=outer_table.`id` ) as `count_in_order`
    FROM 
        `orders_filetypes` as outer_table
    WHERE
        `required`=1 
    ORDER BY `sort`, `title`
```

Comment: no problem, of course, you can use this code. But the point is that the work stopped because of this. and search for the thousands of lines of code in the program, which has used such requests - it is unrealistic long time.

the best option to change the setting, and everything will work as before.